# mysql no response if left join 2 inner join table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have tried to run a SQL statment that Left Join 2 inner join statement, but the MYSQL cannot load the result.

`TableA` about 100,000 records and `TableB` about 200,000 records.

The statement is similar at the below :

(The job is about accounting matters, a aging report, and determine which voucher is not paid)

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM 
 (SELECT tableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id WHERE tableB.dramt != 0) a 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT tableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id WHERE tableB.cramt != 0) b
ON a.invoiceno = b.invoiceno
```

I have tried to run the `INNER JOIN` statement separately, the result has returned in less than a second.

Is it about the server setting? Anyone has similar experience? Please kindly give me some advice with thanks.

Comment: What you SELECT  in your two individual JOIN query?

Comment: so, you like your queries being slow? =) 

the first sub-select creates a large temporary table. the 2nd sub-select creates another large temporary table. for the join you will need another large temporary table. since they are large, they won't fit into ram. thus the db needs to create them on disk. which is slow.

it's not about a server setting, it's about writing a better query. use EXPLAIN to get a sense of what mysqldb is actually doing.

Comment: to write a better query you should first state the goal of the query in plain english / your native language. it's often much easier to translate this back to SQL. imho you want A x B for all B.dramt != 0 or B.cramt != 0 .. but it's hard to tell.

Comment: But I don't understand that I can get the result in a few second from my local computer for development use; but i cannot get the result when I run the same SQL on the Live server. And the hardware of the Live server is far better than my local computer. I feel curious.

Comment: the live-server has real load and is not idling around. you are not just calling "one" statement, you are joining tables, which leads to a lot of scanning the tables up and down to search for the matching rows. in order to have fast joins you need to reduce the number of rows in both tables or come up with a where-clause which reduces the rows while doing the join.

do an "EXPLAIN" to get a sense of what is going on.